# How to stop Angular App being cached (old version) in browser

Tags: angular

We are building our angular app with the cli.  When we deploy it on our server, and navigate to our app.  The old version of the app (components and templates) are received sometimes.  Has anyone else experienced this? Solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds more of a server cache problem... Did you try to clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to serve your `index.html` with `no-cache` or limited cache period.
In Express, it looks like

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=0");
   return next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks you.  We use nginx so I added that header in a similar way.  Leaving the open for a few days to fully vet out.  If we see no more issues I will marked this as the solution.